# Extracting data from a PHP file that containing XML code

Tags: php, xml

Regards,

I have a PHP file that contains XML code located on another server, example: http://proveedor.com/Scores.php

This is the code that I generated the file:

```
<scores>
<game time="Nov 7 2013 05:30:00:000PM">
<sport id="1" name=""/>
<league id="1" name=""/>
<away number="107" name="Washington" abbr="WAS" score="" points="-1" price="-106" ML="-111" opener_points="-1" opener_price="-120" opener_ML="-132"/>
<home number="108" name="Minnesota" abbr="MIN" score="" points="1" price="-104" ML="101" opener_points="1" opener_price="109" opener_ML="120"/>
<status time_remaining="" value=""/>
<total points="48.5" over="-102" under="-108" opener_total="48" opener_over="-105" opener_under="-105"/>
</game>
<game time="Nov 7 2013 04:30:00:000PM">
<sport id="1" name=""/>
<league id="2" name=""/>
<away number="109" name="Oklahoma" abbr="OKL" score="" points="17" price="-112" ML="526" opener_points="14" opener_price="-106" opener_ML="481"/>
<home number="110" name="Baylor" abbr="BAY" score="" points="-17" price="100" ML="-665" opener_points="-14" opener_price="-106" opener_ML="-600"/>
<status time_remaining="" value=""/>
<total points="74" over="-108" under="-104" opener_total="72.5" opener_over="-106" opener_under="-106"/>
</game>
</scores>
```

What I want is to read each information of the  nodes  shown in the above XML code. But I want to from another PHP file located that on another server, called:
http://www.cliente.com/PrintScores.php

forgive me for my bad English...

Comment: http://php.net/file_get_contents http://php.net/dom

Comment: What @MarcB said is, you must use **file_get_contents** on your PrintScores.php to get the xml content from Scores.php and then parse it using **dom**